# My project are not displaying my recyclerView items. what should i do?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am a beginner in android java and there's this project where i have to create a private social apps. Currently there's a problem where my project did not displaying the recyclerView.

this is my MainForum.java:

```
package com.example.a123snap1;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainForum extends Fragment {

    private FloatingActionButton uploadImage;

    private List<ImagePost> imagePostList;
    private String groupCode;
    private String imageId;
    private String groupId;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DatabaseReference groupRef;
    private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;
    private int currentPage = 1;
    private int pageSize = 10;
    private ValueEventListener commentValueEventListener;

    private String likeCount;


    private DatabaseReference commentRef;

    public MainForum() {
        // require a empty public constructor
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_forum, container, false);

        uploadImage = rootView.findViewById(R.id.uploadImageFAB);

        uploadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(requireContext(), UploadActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvPostImage);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        imagePostList = new ArrayList<>();
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(requireContext(), imagePostList, groupCode, imageId);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

        String currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference currentUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(currentUserId);

        currentUserRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    String groupId = dataSnapshot.child("groupId").getValue(String.class);
                    if (groupId != null){

                        groupRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Group").child(groupId);

                        valueEventListener = groupRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                imagePostList.clear();

                                for (DataSnapshot groupSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    String groupId = groupSnapshot.getKey();
                                    if (groupSnapshot.hasChild("images")) {
                                        DataSnapshot imagesSnapshot = groupSnapshot.child("images");
                                        for (DataSnapshot imageSnapshot : imagesSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                            String imageId = imageSnapshot.getKey();
                                            String imageUrl = imageSnapshot.child("imageUrl").getValue(String.class);
                                            String caption = imageSnapshot.child("caption").getValue(String.class);
                                            String userId = imageSnapshot.child("userId").getValue(String.class);

                                            if (imageId != null && imageUrl != null && caption != null && userId != null) {
                                                DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(userId);
                                                userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot userSnapshot) {
                                                        if (userSnapshot.exists()) {
                                                            String username = userSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                                                            String profilePictureUrl = userSnapshot.child("profileImage").getValue(String.class);
                                                            ImagePost imagePost = new ImagePost(groupId, imageId, imageUrl, caption, userId, username, profilePictureUrl);
                                                            imagePostList.add(imagePost);
                                                        }
                                                        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                    }

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                                                        // Handle error condition if necessary
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                // Handle database error
                            }
                        });

                        groupRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                int totalItems = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                                int totalPages = (int) Math.ceil((double) totalItems / pageSize);

                                if (currentPage <= totalPages) {
                                    groupRef.limitToFirst(currentPage * pageSize).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
                                    currentPage++;
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                // Handle database error
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                // Handle database error
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (valueEventListener != null) {
            groupRef.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
        }
        if (commentRef != null){
            commentRef.removeEventListener(commentValueEventListener);
        }
    }

}
```

this is my ImageAdapter.java:

```
package com.example.a123snap1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.CircleCrop;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {

    private List<ImagePost> imagePosts;
    private DatabaseReference likeref, postref;
    private OnItemClickListener listener;
    private Context context;
    private String groupId;
    private String imageId;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<ImagePost> imagePosts, String groupId, String imageId) {
        this.imagePosts = new ArrayList<>();
        this.context = context;
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.imageId = imageId;
        String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        if (groupId != null && imageId != null) {
            postref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("Group")
                    .child(groupId) // Access the specific group node using the groupId
                    .child("images") // Access the images node under the group
                    .child(imageId);

            postref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    imagePosts.clear(); // Clear the list before populating it with new data
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        ImagePost imagePost = snapshot.getValue(ImagePost.class);
                        imagePosts.add(imagePost);
                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notify the adapter that the data has changed
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    // Handle error condition if necessary
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Handle the situation where groupId or imageId is null
        }

        likeref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_item, parent, false);
        return new ImageViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ImagePost imagePost = imagePosts.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        final boolean isLiked = imagePost.isLiked();
        Integer likeCount = imagePosts.get(position).getLikeCount();
        holder.captionTextView.setText(imagePost.getCaption());
        holder.usernameTextView.setText(imagePost.getUsername());
        holder.likeCount.setText(String.valueOf(imagePost.getLikeCount()));

        // Load the image using an image loading library like Picasso, Glide, or Coil
        // For simplicity, we'll use Glide here
        Glide.with(holder.imageView.getContext())
                .load(imagePost.getImageUrl())
                .into(holder.imageView);

        Glide.with(holder.profileImageView.getContext())
                .load(imagePost.getProfilePictureUrl())
                .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(new CircleCrop()))
                .into(holder.profileImageView);

        holder.likePost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImagePost clickedPost = imagePosts.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                String imageId = clickedPost.getImageId();

                likeref.child(groupId)
                        .child(imageId)
                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                    // The user has already liked the post, so remove the like
                                    dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                                } else {
                                    // The user has not liked the post, so add the like
                                    dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(true);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                // Handle error condition if necessary
                            }
                        });
            }
        });


        holder.commentPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImagePost clickedPost = imagePosts.get(position);
                String imageId = clickedPost.getImageId();

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), commentActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("imageId", imageId);
                intent.putExtra("groupId", groupId);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imagePosts.size();
    }

    public static class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView captionTextView;
        public TextView usernameTextView;
        public ImageView profileImageView;
        public TextView likeCount;

        ImageButton likePost, commentPost;

        public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postImage);
            captionTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_caption);
            usernameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username_post);
            profileImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profileImage);
            likePost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likeBtn);
            commentPost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentBtn);
            likeCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likeCount);
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    // Set the listener in the adapter
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

and this is my ImagePost

```
    private String groupId;
    private String imageUrl;
    private String caption;
    private String userId;
    private String username;
    private String profilePictureUrl;
    private String imageId;

    private boolean isLiked;
    private int likeCount = 1;

    public ImagePost(String groupId, String imageId, String imageUrl, String caption, String userId, String username, String profilePictureUrl) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.caption = caption;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.username = username;
        this.profilePictureUrl = profilePictureUrl;
    }

    public ImagePost(){
        //required empty constructor for Firebase deserialization
    }

    public String getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(String groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public String getCaption() {
        return caption;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getProfilePictureUrl() {
        return profilePictureUrl;
    }

    public boolean isLiked() {
        return isLiked;
    }

    public void setLiked(boolean liked) {
        isLiked = liked;
    }

    public int getLikeCount() {
        return likeCount;
    }



    public void setLikeCount(int likeCount) {
        this.likeCount = likeCount;
    }

    public String getImageId(){
        return imageId;
    }

    public void setImageId(String imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
```

I want to show these items inside my recyclerview but it doesn't show at all and I can't see the error. Maybe you guys can help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: try adding a toast in your if(userSnapshot.exists()) block to be sure that the data is being retrieved and if the toast shows up and try also shifting the adapter.notfydataSetChanged inside of if block

Comment: I have tried many things but it still did not work

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).